# I am getting the "no such file to load — openssl" error on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, osx-lion, rvm, libyaml

I am getting the `no such file to load — openssl error` on OSX 10.7.5 in a Ruby on Rails environment.

I read all the related questions here on StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me.

Tried the following:

1. Tried building with openssl specified. Did not work:

   `rvm pkg install openssl`
    
   `rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`
2. Also tried with the system's OpenSSL. Didn't work, too:

   `which openssl`
   `/opt/local/bin/openssl`
    
   `rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local/bin`

   3.Read that `libyaml` is required. I've already have it:

   `brew install libyaml` 
   `libyaml-0.1.4 already installed`

Other info :
My system has ruby version 1.8.7. Everything works (including load SSL) when I use that Ruby. But it is too old for some of the gems I am using. So, I have installed all other versions using RVM. I have also made the necessary environment changes. I tried all these steps with 1.9.2, 1.9.3 both. But same `no such file to Load - OpenSSL error`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues similar to this when installing Ruby 2.0.0. I had to do:

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

(or 1.9.3 in your case)

*[source](https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/)*

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if your mac has an outdated version of OpenSSL or the certificate files. It seems this exact issue started recently with the release of Ruby 2.0, even if that isn't the version you're trying to install with RVM. A friend of mine ran into the same issue earlier this week, nothing on stackoverflow or google was helping.

Check out this link for updating OpenSSL:
http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

EDIT: OSX comes with an outdated version now so if you haven't updated then it will definitely cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this:  http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion

Hope it helps!